# Retrieve job postings for a specific company using LinkedIn's API

Tags: linkedin-api

I have access to a company's unique linked in ID and would like to be able to do a search for its job postings; however, the only company-related input for the `job-search` call is `company-name`, and the `companies` call does not appear to offer job postings in the output.

Is my only option to use the `companies` call to get the company name and then make a separate call with the acquired company name (and then subsequent calls for each returned job so that I can get the title of the position offering)?

I also have access to the company's name on my site, but any discrepancy between my data and LinkedIn's could return postings for other companies or miss the postings I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LinkedIn may someday improve their API to handle requests such as the one needed here.  But for now, it looks like the only way to get all job postings for a company based on the company ID is to make 2 separate preliminary calls (one to acquire the company name using the company ID, then a second to acquire all jobs based on the company name).  Then another call to the API must be made for each job ID returned by the second call.

Answer (score 2):

Linkedin does not expose most of its apis publicly anymore starting from May, 2015. Please go through this link (https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes) for more info. You cannot achieve this anymore unless you are a part of their partnership program. More info here https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs

Answer (score 1):

LinkedIn API for jobs of particular company based on company Id     http://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/(LinkediUniqueCompanyID)/updates?event-type=job-posting

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a couple of different ways.  In neither case do you need to

Using job-search as you noted, you can do this:

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/job-search:(jobs:(id,company:(id,name),position:(title,location,job-functions))&company-name=LinkedIn
```

Note that job-search is a fuzzy match in this case so if you're close, it's probably good enough.  You don't want to include "Inc" if you're looking for a company, though.  The documentation for the job-search API is here:
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/job-search-api

Check the Hacker Summary at the top of the page to see all the different fields you can retrieve with a single call (there's no need to make subsequent calls to get more details).

However, if you've gotten the company ID you can get jobs directly from the job lookup API:
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/job-lookup-api-and-fields

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/jobs/1337:(id,company:(id,name),position:(title,location,job-functions)
```

Again, the same field selectors apply here.  You can request the details for the job in the same query you use to find the jobs in the first place.

Comment: the job lookup API doesn't seem to accept a company ID.  It says that the only input is the job ID.  How can I use the company ID to get jobs using the job lookup API?

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't the API but you might find this plugin that they provide to be useful:

https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/jobs-you-may-be-interested?button-type-yours=true

Just put in your company name and it gives a nice widget with your company's jobs. Again, not really the API but I thought it might accomplish what you wanted anyways.

Comment: The widget (like the API) requires the company name to be inputed.  I need something that gives me job postings based on a company's LinkedIn ID

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, in early 2024, you can also find external Linkedin APIs on [RapidAPI](https://rapidapi.com/category/Jobs), [APIlist](https://apilist.fun/category/jobs), or [APIfy](https://apify.com/store/categories/jobs)

There are APIs that offer the job postings from Linkedin and many other job aggregators, job boards, or company career pages such as:

- https://apify.com/bebity/linkedin-jobs-scraper
- https://rapidapi.com/bebity-bebity-default/api/linkedin-jobs-scraper-api/
- https://jobdatafeeds.com/job-api