# LinkedIn API v2 - Possible to get Company job listings?

Tags: linkedin-api

I've pored over the LinkedIn developer documentation for api v2, and can't find any endpoints or documentation which provides me with a given company's list of jobs. Does anyone know if this is still possible using API v2, and if so, can anyone point me at documentation for this specific use case of their API or give me an example URI for requesting this data?

Thank you!

p.s. This SO post seems to be the most relevant, but it doesn't provide me with a solid answer as it is rather old and refers to api v1 endpoints and functionality: [Retrieve job postings for a specific company using LinkedIn's API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332330/retrieve-job-postings-for-a-specific-company-using-linkedins-api)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is not yet possible with v2. But what I could suggest is that you look at how LinkedIn carries out the job search on their own website. They use Voyager service which pretty much having the endpoints you'll ever need to get your work done.

Have a look: https://linkedin.api-docs.io/v1.0/search/yKaMAGcbmsJBswTCb

Press F12 and inspect the XHR requests flowing out to LinkedIn website when you do a job search. It will give you a lot of hints ;)

Comment: Do you know if Voyager requires authentication to use their API?